# VBA excel rightfax

Tags: excel, vba, rightfax, docx-mailmerge

Currently I have a process in Excel that a user clicks a specific command and then takes the data from Excel and creates a mailmerge in Word. I then want it to the file(s) via RightFax, but I am having trouble at the Set oNewFax, when stepping through I get a run-time error '-2147023174 (800706ba)':. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
    Sub RightFax()

Dim oFaxServer As RFCOMAPILib.faxserver
Dim oNewFax As RFCOMAPILib.fax
Set oFaxServer = New RFCOMAPILib.faxserver
oFaxServer.ServerName = "RightFax Fax Printer"
oFaxServer.UseNTAuthentication = True
Set oNewFax = oFaxServer.User.Faxes.Create

oNewFax.ToFaxNumber = "##########"
oNewFax.ToName = "Testing"
oNewFax.EmailSubject = ""
oNewFax.Attachments.Add ("######")
oNewFax.HasCoversheet = False 'Change to true if you want a coversheet 
generated
oNewFax.Send
Set oFaxServer = Nothing
Set oNewFax = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: It might help if you shared the reference you were using in Excel to use the Right Fax objects.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid response (new to VBA) but by reference are you referring to the RFCOMAPILib (RightFax COM API Type Library)

Comment: Yes, thanks. I will see if I can figure out the problem

Comment: Happen to have any luck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My working code creates the fax object like below...

```
Set oNewFax = oFaxServer.CreateObject(coFax)
```